# WiX created wizard launches the application but doesn't close itself

Tags: wix, wix3.8

I would appreciate your help.
I have an installer made by WiX3.8. I needed to start application after having fulfiled installation. I found [this HowTo](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/ui_and_localization/run_program_after_install.html).
In a word my application is launched, but I still have instalation wizard working. And if I press finish again the app launches again too.
So, there are two part of my wixfile:
I have CustomAction

```
<Property Id="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[#file19_launcher]" />
<CustomAction Id="LaunchApplication" Execute="immediate" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixShellExec" Impersonate="yes" />
```

and ExitDialog in a ui section:

```
 <UI Id="GoWixUI_InstallDir">
        <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" Control="Finish" Event="DoAction" Value="LaunchApplication" Order="1">NOT Installed</Publish>...</UI>
```

Please give me any suggestions you have on it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I was forced to create my own Finish Dialog and add sequence of actions for finish button. But if someone knows why it doesn't work as it was mentioned, please welcome )